# -webkit-fill-available isn't working on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the property `height: -webkit-fill-available`.

For that purpose I built this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJoOWW

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and when I ran the code on Chrome, everything woks fine, but in Firefox I could not make it work.

My Firefox: Firefox Quantum 68.0, Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu, canonical 1.0

EDIT1: Using width: -moz-available did little changes on the layout, but the image isn't displaying in the same way as chrome

EDIT2: The first image is correct (Chrome). The last image is displayed on Firefox, I would like to display the image on Firefox in the same way as Chrome

[image: Right]
[image: Wrong]

Comment: Firefox is not a webkit browser, so the webkit prefix won't work

Comment: A quick search on [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=fill-available) revealed `-moz-available`, did you try that?

Comment: Using width: -moz-available did little changes on the layout, but the image isn't displaying in the same way as chrome

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain clearly what you are trying to do? It would help if you add a snippet that shows what you are trying to achieve and what exactly isn't working, are you just trying to fit the image inside the containing `div`? If yes, right now your div has a fixed height of 85px, just give the same height to your image. If that does not work for you add some details to the post, then we may be able to help better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to fit the image inside the containing div. You can do that with well-supported `CSS` properties. There are many ways, here is one.

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 85px;
}
.img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <a href=''>
    <img class ="img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/monetostatic/email/white-label/ustrike/logo_header.png">
  </a>  
</div>
```

Comment: I made changes on the link, now the img is inside a <a> and a <div>. Could you help me ?

Comment: I updated the post. I am looking at the result in Firefox and it looks exactly like your desired result in Chrome. Some notes, I removed `margin: 0 auto` and `margin-bottom: 0` from your `CSS` the first one does not seem to be doing anything, you only need auto if you want to center, and you are overriding `margin-bottom`, twice, later. I also removed `cursor: pointer` no need since you now have an `a` tag. I added the *required* `href` attribute, I assume you will make it point somewhere later.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply give a `height: inherit;` to your `<img>` and of course to its wrapper `<a>` and you'll see it works exactly like chrome.
also, remove `width: -moz-available;` its useless here.
and with this approach, you won't need `height: -webkit-fill-available;` anymore.
hope it was helpful.